# Redis command to get all available channels for pub/sub?

Tags: redis, comet, publish-subscribe, channel

I search through redis command list. I couldn't find the command to get all the available channels in redis pub/sub. In meteor server, the equivalent command is `LISTCHANNELS`, where it lists all known channels, the number of messages stored on each one and the number of current subscribers.

I have a cron that needs to periodically know about the available channels. Does redis have native command for this? Or I need to find a way to implement it myself?

Comment: You can know no of channels with info command

Answer (score 98, accepted):

`PUBSUB CHANNELS` does this as of version 2.8.0.

Answer (score 13):

There is no existing command - look at http://redis.io/commands#pubsub.
You can save all channels' names in `SET` and retrieve them, when it is required.

Answer (score 11):

List all redis channels (2 ways):

```
PUBSUB CHANNELS
PUBSUB CHANNELS *
```

Or use wild card names:

```
PUBSUB CHANNELS mystarter*
```

They will check the pattern which matchs the strings more reference go to:
http://redis.io/commands/pubsub